# Understand word problems with set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I was reading through probability book with a certain example in it:

```
A = {Sunshine in Melbourne today}
B = {Sunshine in Melbourne today and tomorrow}
```

and it has four answer choices and asks which choice is true:

```
a: A ⊂ B
b: B ⊂ A
c: A ∩ B = { }
d: All of the above
```

Through process of elimination, `c` and `d` are both incorrect as either `a` or `b` have to be the right answer as they are about strict subsets. This is where I get tripped up. The book provided the right answer choice is `B`, but with the information about the sets above, I'm not sure how `B` could be a strict subset of `A`.

The way I'm looking at it now is:

```
A = {1}
B = {1, 2}
```

and in this case, `B ⊂ A` doesn't make sense to me, but `A ⊂ B` does. Can anyone help clarify on this?

Comment: Since it is never sunny in Melbourne, both sets are empty, and all four are true. (Posted on a sunny Sydney afternoon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't think about this as numbers, but as possible events or scenarios: consider all the scenarios in which there is sunshine in Melbourne today, and then consider all the scenarios in which there is sunshine in Melbourne both today and tomorrow: the latter will be a subset of the former.

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

$A$ = {a man is more than $30$ years old}.

$B$ = {a man is more than $30$ years old and has brown eyes}.

Note $A$ has all men above $30$ years old, including the ones with brown eyes.